# Undo unstaged modifications for a single file in git

Tags: git

How can I undo unstaged modifications to a single file?  By unstaged, I mean `git add` has yet to be performed since the last checkout.

Comment: git checkout <filename> is probably that what you are looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the command you're looking for to back out your `local unstaged changes`.

**WARNING**: Any local changes in the file would be lost and the file would be replaced with the one from `HEAD`.

```
git checkout -- filename
```

Comment: This one gets selected because I found the answer in my notes and it matches this one.

Answer (score 3):

Like I already posted in the Comments before,

```
git checkout <filename>
```

is what you are looking for.

For more informations, see http://githowto.com/undoing_staged_changes , its a nice git tutorial.